# Laravel: Send default value to path in web.php

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Good afternoon.

I want that when starting my application, the index path leading to the dashboard receives a default value of 'month', so that the first thing the user sees is the information filtered by month. Already in the Dashboard I have a selector that will make the corresponding filter but I do not know if this affects the route already defined with the default value.

In web.php I have:

```
Route::get('merchant-dashboard/{filterDashboardMerchant}', 'HomeController@index')->name('merchant-dashboard')->middleware(['auth.shopify']);
```

$filterDashboardMerchant is the variable that I use to filter the information to display, it gets values ​​between 'today', 'month' and 'year'.

In the controller I receive it like this:

```
public function index($filterDashboardMerchant)
    {
    .............
    }
```

The filter within the Dashboard view is the following select:

```
<select id="filter-records" class="custom-select-design1">
    <option value="{{ route('merchant-dashboard', $filterDashboardMerchant = 'today') }}" {{$filterDashboardMerchant==='today' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}}>Today</option>
    <option value="{{ route('merchant-dashboard', $filterDashboardMerchant = 'month') }}" {{$filterDashboardMerchant==='month' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}}>Month</option>
    <option value="{{ route('merchant-dashboard', $filterDashboardMerchant = 'year') }}" {{$filterDashboardMerchant==='year' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}}>Year</option>
</select>
```

Maybe it's a matter of syntax, but I've tried several options and none of them work for me. I hope you can help me.

Thank you.

Comment: I am missing comment that what I need is that starting the route is like this:

https://www.myweb.com/merchant-dashboard/month

Comment: what is the actual error you're experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

One option is make parameter optional and in Controller set its default value.

Route:

```
Route::get('merchant-dashboard/{filterDashboardMerchant?}', 'HomeController@index')->name('merchant-dashboard')->middleware(['auth.shopify']);
```

Controller method:

```
public function index($filterDashboardMerchant = 'month')
```